# How to install composer dependencies in a container?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

***What I'm trying to do***

I'm trying to dockerize [this](https://github.com/agungsugiarto/boilerplate) php application builded on CodeIgniter 4. This app have the following dependencies which are normally installed via composer:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3 || ^8.0",
    "myth/auth": "dev-develop",
    "codeigniter4/framework": "^4.1",
    "codeigniter4/translations" : "^4.0"
},
```

The project structure is organized as follows:

```
docker
    database
    nginx
    php-fpm
    docker-compose.yml
src
    ... app files ...
tests
composer.json
```

inside the `docker-compose.yml` I have a service called `php-fpm` which copies all the app files to `/var/www/html` that is the `nginx` public directory:

```
php-fpm:
  container_name: boilerplate_app
  build:
    context: ./php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ../src:/var/www/html
```

What I need to do is install the application dependencies using composer.

***What I tried***

Initially, I though to do this inside the `Dockerfile` available in `php-fpm` folder:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli    

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN composer require --working-dir=../../ app/boilerplate

COPY ./config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

Essentially I have installed `composer` in the container and then I tried to install all the dependencies from the `composer.json` file available in the root of the project.

***The issue***

Unfortunately, when I run the command `docker-compose up --build` this error is raised:

> No composer.json present in the current directory (./composer.json), this may be the cause of the following exception.

seems that the container cannot access to the `composer.json` file or I'm doing something bad with the path parameter `working-dir`.

So, I though to another solution, define another container inside `docker-compose.yml` which have the composer instance separated:

```
composer:
  image: composer:2.0.9
  command: ["composer", "require", "app/boilerplate"]
  volumes:
    - /var/www/html
```

This should read the `composer.json` file from the root and then should install all the dependencies through the command `composer require app/boilerplate`, but again, the same error is raised:

> Composer could not find a `composer.json` file in `/app`.

This is the full `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: boilerplate_app
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    container_name: boilerplate_nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - "8881:80"
      - "8882:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm

  database:
    container_name: boilerplate_db
    build:
      context: ./database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=boilerplate_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_USER=foo
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
    volumes:
      - ./database/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql

  composer:
    image: composer:2.0.9
    command: ["composer", "require", "app/boilerplate"]
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html
```

and this is the `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "app/boilerplate",
    "description": "CodeIgniter4 Boilerplate based on AdminLTE 3 with user management, roles, permissions, ...",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3 || ^8.0",
        "myth/auth": "dev-develop",
        "codeigniter4/framework": "^4.1",
        "codeigniter4/translations" : "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.1",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.13"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "app\\boilerplate\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": [
          "@composer dump-autoload"
        ],
        "test": "phpunit --colors=always -vvv"
    }
}
```

what I can do for fix the problem?

***Folder structure image preview:***

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to make it work? I would assume that `composer require`  is run on **building** the image, while your application data is not present in that image until you run it

Comment: @Nico Haase I tried to run `composer require` inside `php-fpm` 'cause is the container that move the application files in the `nginx` directory. I suppose that composer must be executed in that container: 1. Copy app files 2. Install dependencies

Comment: Yeah, than do that **after** adding your application data to the container

Comment: @Nico Haase I already did this. The problem's that the composer.json file is located in the app directory and Dockerfile is not able to run `composer require`

Comment: Yes, as I assume: running `composer require`  during building the container does not work, as you mount the volume later

Comment: @NicoHaase could you please try to dockerize this boilerplate: https://github.com/agungsugiarto/boilerplate I'm doing something wrong but I don't understand how can I fix this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems you have a couple of problems.

First, you are relying on bind mounts. But those are available at **run-time**, but not at **build-time**.

So you need to copy the `composer.*` files to your docker image before you run `composer install`.

And then, you'll have trouble doing so because you moved the build context to a subdirectory of your project, which would make copying files from parent directories problematic.

To begin with, change the build context, and simply reference the `Dockerfile` you need to build your project:

```yaml
services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: boilerplate_app
    build:
      dockerfile: ./php-fpm/Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
# the rest of your docker-compose.yml
```

After you do this, you need to adjust your `Dockerfile` to account that now its build context is one directory up, and add the required `COPY` statements.

I've also updated the dockerfile to take advantage of Docker multi-stage process

```docker
FROM composer:2 as composer_stage

RUN rm -rf /var/www && mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

# This are production settings, I'm running with 'no-dev', adjust accordingly 
# if you need it
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --no-autoloader

RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize --apcu --no-dev

FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

COPY php-fpm/config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY --from=composer_stage /var/www/html /var/www/html

COPY src src/

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

I've also added a `COPY` statement to copy your projects `src` dir, because otherwise the image you are building has your composer dependencies, and nothing else. This way your application is a properly self-contained container (no pun intended).

You should also make sure `src` mountpoints. Since those do not really pertain to image **building**, but are only used when you are actually **running** the container, I didn't review them very carefully.

Dockerize/containerize an application is first and foremost about building the correct image, then you'll need to create the appropriate usage documentation

Comment: The above is a “working example”. You can use it to fix your version.

Comment: I tried but I'm not able to run it, the error says that Dockerfile is not a valid image. Could you please upload the code?

Comment: I put together a quick "proof of concept" based on this and your project structure [here](https://github.com/yivi/q_66283653). Just tried it with `docker-compose build`, and it builds. You can use it as a starting point to fix your own project.